# Why is USB extension distance so limited?

Tags: usb, cable

The known acceptable range for (for example) an ethernet networking cable before any kind of noticable drop in speed or latency appears is a whole 100 meters for standard class cat5e, cat6 and cat6e cables, and there are variants that can extend this range up to 500 meters and this is for 100mbps, 1gbps and 10gbps speeds depending on what cable you're using...

And I don't know the specs for HDMI, but I'm having absolutely no noticable problems with a 10 meter hdmi cable, and judging by what I saw on the market this should go on for quite some distance beyond this (at least 20m).

Meanwhile over in USB land the maximum distance extension cable I've seen was 3 meters, any longer and it's generally deemed unreliable unless you have a repeater on your cable, and I've actually tested this and if I am extending a USB cable beyond the recommended parameters I start seeing problems (even over 5m with a repeater I have problems) hell, I have a 5 meter cable with no repeater, and it worked for a while shortly after I got it, but then when I tried to connect devices to it after only short use it simply stopped working (windows said unknown/unrecognized device or something like that) and this is only for up to a maximum of 5gbit transfer rates, much lower than what you could acheive with ethernet.

And somehow despite all these problems, it seems like it has no issue with USB Hubs for connecting multiple devices to the same port (as long as they all get powered independently...) but admittedly this too starts degrading if you are using extension cables...

Why does USB have these problems with cable lengths; and only these VERY SHORT lengths when everything else seems to be able to extend pretty much across an entire building without any noticable issues?

And is there anything that can be done to bypass these limitations?

Comment: because USB was designed for short distances.  Mice, keyboards, external hard drives, printers, scanners, etc would be placed near the computer where a user is working.

Comment: @Keltari yes it was, but that's not the reason. Do you think HDMI was specified for long distances?

Comment: HDMI will suffer signal degradation at about 50 feet.  But video cables are designed for lengths longer than something within "arms reach."

Comment: @Cestarian - You don't know the reason, so how can you say the reason Keltari provided, isn't the reason?

Comment: I think the type of solution you can expect is to not actually have long USB cables but rather having the USB signals transported in some other form, such as eg http://www.corning.com/optical-cables-by-corning/worldwide/en/products/usb-optical-cables.html

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yeah that seems like the perfect solution. Might wanna add that as an answer to the question this is now marked a duplicate of.